# Convert Pandas Column to DateTime With Rare Date Format

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, dataframe, string-to-datetime

I have one column on my dataframe that follows this date format:

17 MAY2016

I've tried to follow this reference: http://strftime.org/ and pandas.to_datetime reference: http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.20/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html

My code is as follows:
    `df1 =df1.apply(pandas.to_datetime, errors='ignore', format='%d %b%Y')`

I also tried: `format='%d/%b%Y'` `format='%d /%b%Y'` and still doesn't work. The date column type is still and object.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`to_datetime`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html) only:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date':['17 MAY2016']})

df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'])
print (df)
        date
0 2016-05-17
```

If want format parameter:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%d %b%Y')
print (df)
        date
0 2016-05-17
```

If some non date values add `errors='coerce'` for convert them to `NaT`:

```
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')
```

EDIT:

For check use [`dtypes`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.dtypes.html):

```
print (df.dtypes)
date    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

Comment: first sentence `I have one column`

Comment: Wish I had seen I have one column earlier :(

Comment: `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce')` did the trick. But now the date looks like this: "2016-05-17 00:00:00". How could I format it to a: day-month-year date?

Comment: I think there are some times. If need dates only need `df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], errors='coerce').dt.floor('d')`

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use `.apply`, the `to_datetime` function natively works on pandas Series objects.

```
df1['date column'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['date column'], errors='ignore')
```